# Changing value of form from false to true after showing popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have an HTML page responsible for creating new users on my website.
After creating the user, the website must show a pop-up saying the user was created successfully.

Everything works fine, except that I had to configure an "onsubmit= return false" because I didn't find any other way to display the pop-up without the page redirecting immediately after the submission.
Now the form doesn't save the new users that are being created, so I'm trying to change the form value to true...
How can one do that? returning true after the pop-up closes.

Here is my code so far-

```js
document.getElementById("accountForm").addEventListener("submit", openPopup);
let popup = document.getElementById("popup");
let blur = document.getElementById("blur")

function openPopup() {
  blur.classList.toggle('active')
  popup.classList.add("open-popup");
}

function closePopup() {
  document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active')
  popup.classList.remove("open-popup");
  document.getElementById("accountForm").setAttribute("onsubmit", "true");
  window.location.replace("/login/");
}
```

```css
/* General Styling */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: scale;
}

#blur {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 120vh;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 10vw;
  color: black;
}

p[id="create_account"] {
  color: #b3b3b6;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  color: dimgray;
}


/* Pop-up Styling*/

h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 12vh;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4897d8;
}

h4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 15vh;
  margin: auto;
  color: lightslategray;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: center;
}

button[id="ok"] {
  position: relative;
  top: 23vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #4897d8;
  border: white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  top: -26.5vh;
  left: 34vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  color: lightslategrey;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.popup-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 30vw;
  margin-top: 10vw;
  height: 30vw;
  width: 40vw;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: ease-in;
}

.open-popup {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 500ms;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.container#blur.active {
  filter: blur(20px);
}

.popup.active {
  filter: blur(20px);
}


/* Create Account Styling */

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.5vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 5vh;
}

input[type=text] {
  color: #4897d8;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: lightgray;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 19.5vw;
  height: 6vh;
  background-color: #4897d8;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="popup-container" id="popup">
    <img src="../../static/images/green_tick.png" alt="user created" style="position:relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 7vh; display: block; width:5vw;height:10vh;">
    <h2>Account Creation Succesfull</h2>
    <h4>Thanks for registering with job portal. Your account <br>has been created.</h4>
    <button type="button" id="ok" onclick="closePopup()">Start Recruiting</button>
    <ul class="close" onclick="closePopup()">X</ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="blur">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Create Account
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/recruiters/create_account.css' %}">
      </h1>
      <p id="create_account">Create an account and let us find the best sales<br>talent that satisfy your company's requirements</p>
      <form action="create/created_user" onsubmit="return false" method="post" id="accountForm">
        <form onsubmit="return false" method="post" id="accountForm">
          <p>Recruiter Name*</p>
          <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required>
          <p>Phone Number</p>
          <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
          <p>Email*</p>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required>
          <p>Location</p>
          <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Address">
          <p>Company Name</p>
          <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
          <p>Password*</p>
          <input type="text" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" required>
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Please remove the CSRF from the HTML in the snippet to make a [mcve]

Comment: `window.location.replace("/login/");` will certainly break any submit you want to do

Comment: Removed it, and the replace("/login/") is not my issue...

Comment: I still cannot execute your code. Please make a ***[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)***

Comment: Changed it, supposed to be good now. I am using Django btw.

Comment: You have nested forms, and duplicate ID that is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML, nested form tags with duplicate IDs

You need to submit the form, but if you you actually submit the form, why not show the popup when you return

Here is how to stop and submit when the form is closed

```js
const form = document.getElementById("accountForm")
form.addEventListener("submit", openPopup);
let popup = document.getElementById("popup");
let blur = document.getElementById("blur")

function openPopup(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  blur.classList.toggle('active')
  popup.classList.add("open-popup");
}

function closePopup() {
  document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active')
  popup.classList.remove("open-popup");
  form.submit();
}
```

```css
/* General Styling */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: scale;
}

#blur {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 120vh;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 10vw;
  color: black;
}

p[id="create_account"] {
  color: #b3b3b6;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  color: dimgray;
}


/* Pop-up Styling*/

h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 12vh;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4897d8;
}

h4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 15vh;
  margin: auto;
  color: lightslategray;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: center;
}

button[id="ok"] {
  position: relative;
  top: 23vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #4897d8;
  border: white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  top: -26.5vh;
  left: 34vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  color: lightslategrey;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.popup-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 30vw;
  margin-top: 10vw;
  height: 30vw;
  width: 40vw;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: ease-in;
}

.open-popup {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 500ms;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.container#blur.active {
  filter: blur(20px);
}

.popup.active {
  filter: blur(20px);
}


/* Create Account Styling */

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.5vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 5vh;
}

input[type=text] {
  color: #4897d8;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: lightgray;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 19.5vw;
  height: 6vh;
  background-color: #4897d8;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="popup-container" id="popup">
    <img src="../../static/images/green_tick.png" alt="user created" style="position:relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 7vh; display: block; width:5vw;height:10vh;">
    <h2>Account Creation Succesfull</h2>
    <h4>Thanks for registering with job portal. Your account <br>has been created.</h4>
    <button type="button" id="ok" onclick="closePopup()">Start Recruiting</button>
    <ul class="close" onclick="closePopup()">X</ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="blur">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Create Account
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/recruiters/create_account.css' %}">
      </h1>
      <p id="create_account">Create an account and let us find the best sales<br>talent that satisfy your company's requirements</p>
      <form action="create/created_user" method="post" id="accountForm">
        <p>Recruiter Name*</p>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required>
        <p>Phone Number</p>
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <p>Email*</p>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required>
        <p>Location</p>
        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Address">
        <p>Company Name</p>
        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
        <p>Password*</p>
        <input type="text" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and it didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution.
Used an event listener on the submit button to prevent the default course of action, then showed the pop-up.
Afterward, removed the pop-up and told the form what action needs to be done and to submit.
This is how it looks!

```js
<script>
    const form = document.getElementById("accountForm");
    let popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    let blur = document.getElementById("blur")

    function closePopup(){
        document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active')
        popup.classList.remove("open-popup");
        form.action = "/create/created_user";
        form.submit()
    }
    document.getElementById("accountForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        blur.classList.toggle('active');
        popup.classList.add("open-popup");
    });
</script>
```

```html
# POPUP HTML CONFIGURATION
<div class="popup-container" id="popup">
    <img src="../../static/images/green_tick.png" alt="user created" style="position:relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 7vh; display: block; width:5vw;height:10vh;">
    <h2>Account Creation Succesfull</h2>
    <h4>Thanks for registering with the job portal. Your account <br>has been created.</h4>
    <button type="button" id="ok" onclick="closePopup()">Start Recruiting</button>
    <ul class="close" onclick="closePopup()">X</ul>
</div>

#FORM CONFIGURATION
        <form method="post" id="accountForm">
        <p>Recruiter Name*</p>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required>
        <p>Phone Number</p>
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <p>Email*</p>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required>
        <p>Location</p>
        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Address">
        <p>Company Name</p>
        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
        <p>Password*</p>
        <input type="text" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
        </form>
```